# Clarification Regarding Element Identification in Forge Viewer 4D Simulation

Tags: simulation, autodesk-forge, 4d

I hope this message finds you well. I am writing to discuss a matter concerning our ongoing development of the 4D simulation in the Forge Viewer.

As part of our project, we frequently interact with the model data in the Forge Viewer. Recently, we encountered a challenge when making modifications to the model, such as removing or adding elements. The issue revolves around our need to uniquely identify each element within the viewer.

Traditionally, we have relied on the 'dbId' (database identifier) as a unique input to identify elements. However, we have discovered an alternative identifier known as 'ElementId.' While using 'ElementId' has its advantages, such as consistency across data alterations, it presents a drawback when attempting to identify elements at the parent level.

This situation has prompted us to seek a resolution that allows us to maintain both the uniqueness of element identification and the ability to identify elements within their parent context.

We are open to suggestions and would greatly appreciate your insights on how we can best address this challenge. Your expertise and guidance are invaluable to us as we strive to enhance our 4D simulation capabilities in the Forge Viewer.

Thank you for your time and consideration. We look forward to your feedback and working collaboratively to find a suitable solution.